# Was the strict module introduced between Augustus, version 0.5.3.0 and 0.6?

Tags: python

I am trying to diagnose an install of the python lib augustus (for PMML), and following the [tutorial](http://augustusdocs.appspot.com/docs/v06/model_abstraction/augustus_and_pmml.html#sec_Interactive%20Augustus%20tutorial) (which was written for 0.6 alas), and wondering: Was the strict module introduced between Augustus, version 0.5.3.0 and 0.6?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [their source control](https://code.google.com/p/augustus/source/list?path=/trunk/augustus-pmml-library/augustus/strict.py&start=774)?

Comment: Yes. The *real* question is "where is the tutorial for 0.5.3", assuming one exists.

Comment: Since the source control indicates strict only appeared in 0.6, I'd say documentation for it was non-existent back then.

Comment: This question should be re-opened because the alleged duplicate no longer exists.

Comment: It would be nice to know WHY it was removed, but since it's gone I'm voting to reopen as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are links to various sets of documentation on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/opendatagroup/augustus) - `augustus.strict` is listed in 0.6beta but not 0.5.3.